# A Dynamic Programming Question

Tags: dynamic-programming

> $\underline{\text{Household Sector:}}$ 
>  
>  The household comprises of a single agent whose objective function is to maximize the expected value of his lifetime utility which is a function of consumption of domestically produced goods and imported goods, real money balances, and leisure: 
>   $$\max_{C_t,\frac{M_t}{P_t},H_t,D_{t+1},B_{t+1}}\dfrac1{1-\rho}E_t\sum_{t=0}^\infty \beta^i\left[
> a(C_{t+i}^{1-\rho}+b\left(
> \frac{M_{t+i}}{P_{t+i}}
> \right)^{1-\rho}
> +(1-a-b)\ln(1-H_{t+i})^{1-\rho}
> \right]
> $$ 
>   Subject to the budget constraint: $$B_{t+1}+C_t+\frac{M_t}{P_t}+D_{t+1}=\left(\frac{W_t}{P_t}\right)H_t-T_t+\frac{M_{t-1}}{P_t}+(1+i_t^D)D_t+\Pi_t+(1+i^B_t)B_t$$

Hi I'm trying to solve an economic problem but I haven' learned dynamic programming before. Need to derive the first order conditions. I'd really appreciate if you could lend me your brain for a sec. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I think that the method of Lagrange multipliers will suit you best in this case. This is the wikipedia link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier

Comment: Hi Marc, will it be all right if I perform differentiation in the expectations operator? Thanks!

Comment: Ai, I didn't realize there was an expectation operator in there. You generally cannot differentiate within the expectation, so that poses a problem (which I don't really know how to solve). Maybe someone else can help from here on.